# JSON Deserialization in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, gson, json-deserialization

Is there a JSON Deserialization equivalent of Java's  Google JSON in Ruby. With-out the necessity of defining any custom serializer or deserializer for each class, one can write a one-line code to convert JSON string into custom Java class as shown here under.

**`Address address=gson.fromJson(addressJsonStringForm, Address.class);`**

To accomplish this , one need-not put any annotations/interfaces in Address class nor write separate Deserializer utility  for every class that we need to deserialize. This  makes it very easy to deserialize/serialize classes from third party libraries. There are quite a lot of options on whether to serialize nulls / include /exclude certain attributes etc. I 'm looking for such a versatile JSON from and to custom object serialization/deserialization utility in Ruby. I 'm new to Ruby.

**Reference:**

https://dzone.com/articles/deserializing-json-java-object

Comment: What is wrong with [`JSON.parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.2/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Parsing+JSON)?

Comment: You will get an HashMap from JSON Parse, not the custom/domain object representation ASFAIK. @spickermann

Comment: @Vineel Rubists deal differently with objects. Do you really need a "custom/domain" object representation?

Comment: @vnbrs what makes you think that we never need "domain" object back from JSON String ? Isn't there such an  utility in Ruby?

Comment: @Vineel the fact Ruby is not Java in terms of data typing (dynamic + strong typing) =). Btw, I did NOT say that we never need "domain".

Comment: I still don't see a reason why `JSON.parse` doesn't answer this question, as @spickermann said.

Comment: I was wondering if we can mention that we want it to be De-serialized it to a certain type of object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jsonapi-rb](http://jsonapi-rb.org/guides/deserialization/deserializing.html)

```rb
    DeserializablePost.call(json_hash)
```

[roar](https://github.com/trailblazer/roar#introduction)

```rb
    song = Song.new(title: "Medicine Balls")
    SongRepresenter.new(song).from_json('{"title":"Linoleum"}')
    song.title #=> Linoleum
```

[Netflix - fast_jsonapi](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi)

```rb
    json_string = MovieSerializer.new(movie).serialized_json
```

Answer (score 7):

You can convert it into a Hash using the JSON module:

```
require 'json'

hash = JSON.parse('{"age":18, "name":"Vinicius"}')
hash["age"]
=> 18
```

If you want to convert it to a "structured" object, you can use OpenStruct:

```
require 'json'
require 'ostruct'

person = JSON.parse('{"age":18, "name":"Vinicius"}', object_class: OpenStruct)
person.name
=> "Vinicius"
```

> An OpenStruct is a data structure, similar to a Hash, that allows the definition of arbitrary attributes with their accompanying values. This is accomplished by using Ruby's metaprogramming to define methods on the class itself. [(docs)](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html)

OpenStruct may help you if you don't always know the JSON keys, as it dynamically creates an object.

Comment: Note: depending on how much performance matters to you, OpenStruct WILL slow you down over just using a Hash, or using a class or Struct. You may want to benchmark things at some point.

Comment: @vnbrs Upon opening the link, this is what I see. "Maintenance of Ruby 2.0.0 ended on February 24, 2016."

Comment: I would use [hashie](https://github.com/intridea/hashie) before this. I’ve literally never seen someone use OpenStruct in production code anywhere, ever.

Comment: Well, if you use Rails, you use OpenStruct, as Rails uses it in some parts of Active Storage, if I can recall correctly. Ruby plain Struct may be an alternative. It doesn't have this deep recursion OpenStruct has.